# Debuging with firebug or google chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, firebug

I need to debug my javascript using firebug or google chrome but my javascript is in the same file with the html, when I try to find my javascript code I dont know where is it becase it is not in a specific file it is in the same file with my html, if I use the firebug or google chrome debuger I find the script tab but then I dont know in what file is my javascript because it is not in a javascript file , how can I to find my javascript to debug?

The problem is because I am using ASP.MVC and I have only one view and many partial views that I put in the view, the view has a lateral menu when someone click on the option in the lateral menu one partial view is loaded next to the lateral menu, so this partial view has html and javascript but this new javascript in the partial view is not found for me in firebug or google chrome devtools because only is showed the firs html and script to the view and the code of partial view is not showed in these tools because this code was inserted dinamically and the firebug not refresh it.

What can be the solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**You can know error in which line .look here**
[image]

**you can see file name and number of line error and when you click in name of file you will get 
error line.**

[image]

Comment: thanks, but I add new information in my question because my situation is not common, please read it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the URL. For example, this page, I can put a break point in the file "debuging-with-firebug-or-google-chrome". I believe Google Chrome works similarly.

Also, they're sorted by domain, so that should help you find the URL's file.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox build-in debugger (Main menu button > Developer > Debugger, or CTRL+SHIFT+S) lists all files that contains loaded scripts in left sidebar 'Sources'. It contains even html files if they contain `<script>` tag with content inside. You can check it out at stackoverflow.com.

[image: Firefox debugger at stackoverflow.com] The picture shows debugger with loaded html file.

Sometimes a file may be not present in the list because there were an error during loading of the script. Check "Console" tab to see any javascript errors. Similar feature (reporting errors to Console) also provide both Firebug and Chrome devtools.

**Edit:**

There is a bug / misleading behavior in both Firefox and Chrome. In order to see all scripts (especially those deferredly loaded) it is necessary to open debugger window before the page starts loading. Deferred scripts are shown only if the debugger is open by the time scripts are loaded.

Comment: thanks, but I add new information in my question because my situation is not common, please read it.

Comment: About gradual augmenting page using `<script>` tag: I managed to replicate this bug in Firefox standard debugger (it uses the same internal API as FireBug) and Java web framework GWT. It

Comment: Sorry, text try: About gradual augmenting page using `<script>` tag: I managed to replicate this bug in Firefox standard debugger (it uses the same internal API as FireBug) and Java web framework GWT. It seems like it matters when the debugger tab is shown. It seems like deffered loading of `script` tag emits an event that debugger can process and visualize. And if the debugger is closed at that time, the event is missed and information about new `<script>` tag lost. I.e. in case of Firefox: try to open debugger even before loading page and try to report bug at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/.